Как сделать так, чтобы телеграмм-бот не спамил после перезапуска, aiogram 3
Я новичок. У меня есть бот для телеграмма, написан он на aiogram 3, python. Проблема состоит в том, что если бот вырубается, а пользователь продолжает отправлять ему сообщения, то при повторном запуске бота он начинает спамить, отвечая на заданные во время неактивности команды. Это можно как-то исправить? Ну, чтобы как только я снова запускаю бота, он "забывал" все те сообщения?

Можно перед запуском бота напрямую через api послать запрос на очистку очереди сообщений как вариант ‍♀️

Как это сделать, не подскажите?

Оставил вам ответ, попробуйте. Если решение вам подойдёт, не забудьте его принять.

В Aiogram есть метод deleteWebhook
Вызываете его и всё, накопленные апдейты будут пропущены
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher

async def main():
    bot = Bot(token="TOKEN")
    dp = Dispatcher()
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True) # этот
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

